# How to alter datatables ajax.data request body on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I would like to fetch data on page load and then have filters that can be clicked to refetch the data. The query is a post request because the query parameters are complex and should be represented as json for logical grouping.

The code is as follows:

```js
// table initialization
table = $('my_table').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  ajax: {
    url: 'api/v1/get_documents',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: () => {
      return JSON.stringify({
        doc_filters: {
          archived: false,
          doc_type: 'accounting'
        },
      })
    },
  },
  columns: my_columns,
});


$('#archive_button').click(() => {
  table.ajax.data = () => {
    return JSON.stringify({
      project_filters: {
        archived: true,
      }
    });
  };
  table.ajax.reload();
})
```

I would like the request body to reflect the new project_filters state with archived = true, refetch the data with this new request body, and update the table to reflect the new data. This does not update the request json body.

Comment: Just a suggestion, as I have not tested your specific scenario. The [`reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) function re-uses the `ajax` definition _as defined in the DataTable configuration_. Although you are using a function for your `data`, the actual `archived` value in the function is hard-coded to `false`. My approach in similar situations is to make that a variable (initially set to `false`), and then have the `click()` event update the value of the variable to `true`, prior to calling `reload()`. There may be other/better approaches, also.

Comment: I was able to use your philosophy to come up with a solution. Thank you @andrewJames

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @andrewJames's suggestion I was able to refactor my code as follows:

```js
// table initialization
table = $('my_table').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  ajax: {
    url: 'api/v1/get_documents',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: () => {
      archiveStatus = $('#archive_button').val();
      documentType = $('#document_type').val();
      return JSON.stringify({
        doc_filters: {
          archived: archiveStatus,
          doc_type: documentType
        },
      })
    },
  },
  columns: my_columns,
});


$('#archive_button, #document_type').click(() => {
  table.ajax.reload();
})
```